# Cover background making background-image unresponsive

Tags: html, css

```css
#section{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    background: url("http://cdn9.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/ubuntu-human-1440x900.jpg") no-repeat center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section id="section"></section>
</body>
```

When `background-size` is set to `cover` the image changes its size to cover the window when window size is changed.
Is there any way to cover `background` totally at the start and then when after window size is changed to make the image unresponsive ?

Comment: I think you can do it with javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

How about remove the `background-size` instead. the image will be shown as it's original size.

```css
#section{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    background: url("http://cdn9.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/ubuntu-human-1440x900.jpg") no-repeat center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section id="section"></section>
</body>
```

Comment: image won't cover the whole background if it is small.

Comment: Neither will your current code. And if you want the background to look nice you wouldn't want it to stretch beyond its limits in the first place.

Comment: I don't want to scretch it. I just want it to cover the whole window. But not zoom out when window size is smaller than the image size

Answer (score 1):

Change `background-size:cover;` to `background-size: 100% 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;;`

And it will be like that.

```
#div{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    background: url("http://cdn9.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/ubuntu-human-1440x900.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


<body>
    <div id="section"></div>
</body>
```

Visit [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background-size2)

Or you can use it:

```
  body{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    background: url("http://cdn9.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/ubuntu-human-1440x900.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;

}

  <body></body>
```

Or can check this [link](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: This will still change the size of the div (and background image)  after you resize the page.

Comment: But this will change images size, which makes images ugly

Comment: what you exactly needed?? the picture stretch as the monitor wide, ... so you can choose the second option

Comment: I want the image to cover background but without scretching it

Comment: Yes, but when you change window size image shouldn't change in size

Comment: you can check the 2nd one, and it will change based on windows size

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90968/discussion-between-shuvo-shuvo-and-developer).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to make your background image fill the screen on load, and then not resize afterwards (which i would reconsider - but maybe im not seeing the big picture, no pun intended ;) )

A possible option is to load the image in a seperate div, set the `z-index:-9999;` (which will make the div sit below all the other divs), and then use javascript to determine the size of the image/div when it covers the whole page and change the size of the div with javascript `element.style.width = ""`

```js
window.onload = function(){
  theWidth = document.getElementById("background").offsetWidth;
  theHeight = document.getElementById("background").offsetHeight;
  document.getElementById("background").style.width = theWidth;
  document.getElementById("background").style.height = theHeight;
}
```

```css
#background{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    background: url("http://cdn9.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/ubuntu-human-1440x900.jpg") no-repeat center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section id="background"></section>
    <section id="your_content"></section>
</body>
```

If you wish to make it so that it does not overflow and give you horizontal scrolling after it loads, wrap the background in a `<div style = 'max-width:100%; overflow:hidden; position:relative;'>` div - `overflow:hidden;` will hide all content that overflows that divs bounds (like the div holding the image inside of it which will be at the original width while current width could be smaller) and `position:relative;` is needed for the `overflow:hidden;` to apply (IIRC - if i remember correctly)

Comment: Maybe there is way to do in only css?

Comment: It may be possible - try and see if Noval's answer will work. He may be onto it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do apply a .cover class via jQuery on initial page load and remove it when the window gets resized, like so:

```
$('section#section').addClass('cover');
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    $('section#section').removeClass('cover');
});
```

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/halloecho/jfzuhbn6/)

Comment: image is not covering window totally

Comment: check my fiddle again, I updated the body class https://jsfiddle.net/halloecho/jfzuhbn6/